# Akka http dockering issue ( in compose only )

Tags: scala, docker, akka-http

I have akka http simple app with db connection, to dockerize it I use **sbt native packager** plugin.
If I run database like:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

and the app:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --network="host" --rm my-system-backend:0.1
```

everything works fine, I can make curl requests, app is making proper DB calls etc.
But it does not work when I use docker-compose, I have error then:

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    image: my-system-backend:0.1
    environment:
      DB_URL: "jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/db"
    ports:
     - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
    volumes:
      - ./databasedata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

part of build.sbt:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(
    Defaults.itSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= ...,
    dockerExposedPorts ++= Seq(8080)
  )
  .enablePlugins(FlywayPlugin, JavaAppPackaging)
```

any ideas why this is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see, I missed: `network_mode: "host"` in docker-compose file